# print result set value as text in html page

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-7

I tried this nameString.jsp to make a var so I can call it in web page. All I want is to show the value from my table (SELECT fullname from personel_data where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'") so it would print "Hello, 'myfullname'!"

```
<%
try{
String user=request.getParameter("user");
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection 
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tz","root","");  
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from personel_data where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
       if(rs.next()){
           String name=rs.getString("fullname");
           System.out.print(name);
       }
    }
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

on web page response.jsp

```
<%@include file="nameString.jsp"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello <%= name%>!
</body>
</html>
```

if I remove <%= name%>, "Hello" will appear in the web, but if there is <%= name%> it will fail to compile.

Comment: As `name` is only within scope for the `if` statement, then where you are trying to print it out it will be out-of-scope.  Howver same yourself a lot of trouble and learn about MVC where by the `servlet` will be getting the data and the JSP is primarily for display

Comment: thx for the advice, I'm new to this. I'll learn about MVC right away

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the name variable outside the try statement.This thing make the scope of "name " variable is global. And you can use it in another file

```
 <%
    String name ="";
    try{
    String user=request.getParameter("user");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tz","root","");  
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from personel_data where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
           if(rs.next()){
               name=rs.getString("fullname");
               System.out.print(name);
           }
        }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }

%>
```